# Change tracking in OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice

If e.g.: I delete/modify a few words in a .doc file that is edited with OpenOffice how can I highlight those changes? Under microsoft office it works pretty good.

Where is this feature in OpenOffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I have Polish-only version of interface currently, so I'm translating the menu entries.) Look under `Edit`->`Changes` sub-menu.